# Const-correctness for C++ classes

Tags: c++, constants

```
class SomeClass {
  public:
    void Render() const;

  private:
     mutable Cache m_some_cache;
};
```

Is the class above const-correct? When can I safely say "This operation doesn't change the internal state of an instance"?

In the above example SomeClass is something that renders stuff on the screen. It uses a cache (for example OpenGL buffer objects) to allow faster processing for further calls. So the only thing that changes internally is the cache object. I'm asking myself if a cache already belongs to an internal state of a renderer.

The example is very minimal, but in my real application this goes down a road with many classes, i.e. a lot of Render() calls are involved, and most of them do caching only. But some do also load resources through a resource loader -- is the assumption here still right that a method may be const even if it queries a resource manager for loading a resource?

Comment: Const correctness doesn't relate to changing the internal state of an instance, it relates to changing the _observable_ state of an instance.

Comment: @ildjarn, this could be a good answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it this way. This is perfectly valid:

```
void Type::print_self () const {
    std::cout << *this << std::endl;
}
```

You aren't modifying the object itself, so the use of the `const` qualifier is perfectly valid. This method is modifying `std::cout`, but that doesn't count as far as the `const`ness of `Type::print_self()` goes.

That said, `mutable Cache` looks to me to be a contradiction in terms unless you are only using that `Cache` element for local storage within `Render`. If you are truly using it as a cache it seems a bit dubious to qualify this element as `mutable`. Use it as a cache (e.g., across calls to `Render` rather than within a call to `Render`) and you have lied to both the compiler and to the user of the class.

**Edit**
Per the comments made by the OP, the `Render` method truly is the graphical equivalent of `print_self()`. The 'real' state of the object (presumably not shown for the sake of constructing a minimal working example) presumably isn't modified by rendering. Designating `Render` as a `const` method is the right thing to do. If the `Cache` data member reason for being is to serve as speed bump that avoids the cost of constructing and destructing it with each call to `Render` there is nothing wrong with qualifying that `Cache` member as `mutable` (which is needed so that `Render` can remain `const`).

Comment: `Render` is indeed the only one who uses the cache. I like your example, but let me extend it a bit. Imagine you've got `SnippetManager` that provides text snippets, with a method `GetSnippet( id )`. If you provide a snippet ID in `print_self()` that's unknown, the manager loads it. So `SnippetManager`'s _state_ is changed (not to the outside, because it will always return the same values); is it okay to declare `GetSnippet()` as const?

Comment: @Tank: If I was reviewing that `SnippetManager` code, I would look askance at `GetSnippet` being qualified as `const`. That said, I intentionally used `print_self` because I assumed that your `Render` method is the graphical equivalent of `print_self`. Your use of `const` and `mutable` here are probably fine if the cache is used only for rendering and you made it an instance variable as opposed to a local variable within `Render` for performance reasons. Do be ready to justify your use of `const` and `mutable` here during code review (assuming you have code reviews).

Comment: Thank you very much. As your answer & comments pointed me into the right direction, I set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

When we say "the internal state doesn't change" we mean a purely ***logical*** thing. It is a ***logical*** decision whether changing of `m_some_cache` changes the object state. Const-correctness is a ***logical*** question. So, if you think that from a user's point of view changing `m_some_cache` doesn't affect the object state (in a ***logical*** sense) then the code is const-correct.

In your particular case, I believe it is OK.

Comment: Okay, that's clear, but let us take this a little bit further: In Render(), a call is made to SomeResourceManager::GetImage( id ). If the image for that ID hasn't been loaded yet, it's being loaded, stored in the manager and returned. Would you say it may still be const? (because without it, I can't declare some of my Render() methods const ;)).

Comment: @Tank: Yes, as a matter of fact I would.

Comment: @Tank: modifying the `SomeResourceManager` is fine in a const member function anyway, provided that the state of the resource manager isn't considered part of the state of this object.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Well, the resource manager's only state consists those resources. But in fact there will never be any side-effects when loading resources, so it can be assumed that my resource manager doesn't has any "real" internal state at all.

Comment: @Tank: it might have state - the fact of which resources it has loaded. Suppose it loads resources from disk. Suppose further that you load a file from disk, and then later you modify the file on disk. Unless the resource manager detects this and invalidates its cache record of that resource, then it has externally-visible state.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: That doesn't happen, it's an operation that happens only once, but your thinking is perfectly reasonable. Like in another comment, I should think about splitting up loading and getting resources from the manager.

Answer (score 3):

> When can I safely say "This operation doesn't change the internal state of an instance"?

This question is of logical matter. Usually mutable members are not considered as the internal state, but rather as an implementation artifact.
So, the documentation of your class generally should describe what is considered to be the internal state, it can leave alone the mutable members.

`const` concerns only the internal state of the object. `const`-methods can legitimately alter external state. Here the pointer analogy comes to mind: `char * const p` is a constant pointer but it can alter the pointed-to value. So your example with resource manager seems correct too.

Comment: Okay I see. But to make it work, the resource manager's methods also need to be const, which would be like this: const Resource& GetResource( const string& id ) const. If the resource hasn't been loaded yet, the manager will do it. So the container that holds the resources in the manager needs to be declared mutable. I wonder if that's still a good design. :)

Comment: @Tank I don't get it. Again, const method can access not-const ones of another (non-const) object. So we should talk about resource manager alone without the SomeClass class, here you can consider the loaded resources to be the part of its observable state and not declare GetRc as const.

Comment: So it would be naturally better to split up loading and fetching resources into separate methods (so that `Load()` would be non-const and `Get()` const). I didn't do this just for convenience, but it's probably the better choice regarding the design.

Comment: I still don't see the reason: just make it non-const. You will be unable to call it if ResourceManager _itself_ is const. But it looks fairly logical to me. Why would anyone holding just the const reference to ResourceManager be able to load resources using it? Where does this requirement come from?

Comment: Hypothetically: you can provide a const function IsLoaded(id) for example, then a user holding a const reference could test whether the particular resource is already loaded, and then use that const Get method you proposed in the prev. comment, but what if it is _not_ loaded? Looks like a dead end to me. If he could find some non-const reference in this case, why don't use it in the first place?

Comment: Well, while reviewing my code, I encountered one critical part: The resource manager includes a "base path" where it loads resources from. Theoretically that path can be changed at any time, so the Get()ters may return different values.
I solved the problem by splitting it up in three methods: `Get() const`, `Load()` and `IsLoaded() const`. Works flawlessly.
When a resource doesn't exist, loading it is tried at the right place. If the resource can't be loaded, I've got a serious problem anyway. ;) Besides of that all my `Render()`s are const now and only _query_ the manager for stuff.

Answer (score 2):

As @ildjarn observed, const-correctness refers to the observable, not the internal state of an object; that's why `mutable` is useful.

Then again, if you're actually rendering things, then the observable state of an object *representing the screen* cannot reasonably be `const`, IMHO, since it would break if you later added an inspection method to find out what is on-screen/in the frame buffer.

If `SomeClass` does not represent the screen, then I would expect `Render` to take a mutable reference to, say, a `Screen` object as an argument. Logically, *something* has to change, even if it isn't the `SomeClass` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Const-correctness is about the state of the object as seen from the outside.

If all calls to member functions continue to return the same result, the object's state is logically the same.

Answer (score 2):

The question to ask yourself is, "does calling the `Render` function change the defined state or future behavior of the object, as far as users are concerned?"

Assuming that your cache really is just a resource cache, then presumably modifying the cache doesn't change the functional behavior, just makes it potentially faster. Since your class doesn't offer a guarantee of how slow it is, that doesn't change the defined state or behavior as far as callers are concerned. So it's a valid candidate for a `mutable` member, to be modified by `const` member functions.